# How to convert OpenMP sections to fork()

Tags: c++, pthreads, fork, openmp

I am new to pthreads and would like to ask how to express something like:

```
while(imhappy())
{
 #pragma omp sections
 {
  #pragma omp section
  {
   dothis();
  }
  #pragma omp section
  {
   dothat();
  }
 }
}
```

in an equivalent construct using fork() or vfork() ?
Thanks ahead!

PS: I included the **while** around the sections in case it is somehow more clever to **fork** before the entering the loop due to some resource cloning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP does lots of other things behind the scenes than merely spawning threads. It also distributes code segments and synchronises the different threads. You have tagged your question as `pthreads` though you are asking about implementation with `fork()` which is confusing. In Linux `fork()` is very heavyweight as it creates new processes and rather `clone()` is used to create threads.

Nevertheless, the rough equivalent of an OpenMP sections construct with two threads would be to fork, afterwards an `if` construct has to follow and the master process would execute the `dothis()` path while the child will execute the `dothat()` path. The return value from `fork()` is different in the parent and in the child processes and can be used to make the decision for the branch. The parent process will then wait for the child to finish with `waitpid()` which will be analogous to the implicit barrier synchronisation at the end of the `omp sections` region.

One caveat though - `fork()` is implemented using COW (copy-on-write) pages. What it means is that although at the beginning the memory content of the child is equal to the memory content of the parent, any changes made are private - the child will not see what the parent modifies in its own memory and vice versa. Memory has to be explicitly shared between the two using either SysV shared memory primitives or shared file mappings.

You might really want to look into using POSIX threads API instead.

`vfork()` is a syscall designed for completely different purpose and is not suitable for process cloning at all.

Comment: So considering pthreads it would juist become:

    pthread_create(&tid1,0,dothis,0);
    pthread_create(&tid2,0,dothat,0);
    pthread_join(tid1,0);
    pthread_join(tid2,0);

? this would ndeed be alot easier, and if i see this correctly i ge shared memory by default? Thanks this could be lot easier thn fork!

Comment: No need to call `pthread_create` twice - you already have the other thread :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a straight simulation of sections using the fork.
However, you can theoretically simulate it using a messgae passing mechanism where the shared variables are kept with a root machine. All the openMP flush will happen using the root. (Remember that openMP uses weaker than weak consistency model).